# Symfony 1.4 - Accessing values from the parent of an embedded form in an instance of sfValidatorCallback

Tags: symfony-1.4

$values seems to be sandboxed to that of the form you are calling the sfValidatorCallback from.

I need to be able to query a posted value from the parent form against something in the embedded form I'm calling the post validator from. Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the possibility of overwriting the form submit/validation method in the form class to pass these value when the parent::method() is being called?